# jsessionid from wrong session is getting set in cookie fro JBOSS7.2

Tags: session, jboss

For session fixation prevention we have added
oldsession.invalidate();
newSession = req.getSession(true);
Here jboss is setting same cookie (from invalidated session) as JSESSIONID

Comment: Problem here is jboss is setting the same cookie  from oldsession, but it sets expiry date as 1 Jan 1970 (expired)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Issue, was with Session Fixation prevention code.
- Here we were invalidation session by,
  oldSession.inValidate();
- and then we were getting new session.
  request.getSession(true);

**Solution to this is,
- inValidate session in new thread, and make current thread wait for its execution.**